# How to animate ImageView form center to the top in android?

Tags: android, android-animation

I just want to animate a ImageView like TranslateAnimation which should move form center(As the ImageView is in center of LinearLayout in Layout.xml) to top of the screen. I use this...

```
TranslateAnimation moveLefttoRight = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, 0, -200);
```

I work, But I want to Scale out while image is moving to the top... How I can combine both animations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This tutorial seems to point in the right direction: http://www.barebonescoder.com/2010/06/android-development-more-animations-part-2/